# android username login questions

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I'm creating an app which requires used to create an account and then log in with it. It should keep them logged in for every use after. The usernames would then be used to communicate with others. How do I go about doing all of this? I haven't done anything like it and I don't really know where to start. Any links or advice is appreciated. Thanks! BTW, I'm using eclipse and it's an android application.

Comment: Make a concept, divide it into subtasks, and solvle one problem at a time. Then you can ask specific questions. One problem might be asking user for username, one problem is storing the username, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You should implement **User sessionmanager** using **shared preference**.First you should learn what shared preference actually is.For that consult [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) or [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_shared_preferences.htm).

After that when you are ready to go, check [this](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/08/android-session-management-using-shared-preferences/). Link 3 will meet all the requirements.But first learn about shared preferences.

Answer (score 1):

1) So as I understand you wanna maintain the session of the user by their username that means when you're login into your app your sending the username as intent Extra to query the database using username so first, you create a Java class for a user like this

```
public class User {

private String username;


Context context;
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;


public User(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
    sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences("userinfo", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

}

public void remove() {
    sharedPreferences.edit().clear().commit();
}


public String getUsername() {
   username = sharedPreferences.getString("username", "");
  return username;
}

public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
sharedPreferences.edit().putString("username", username).commit();
}}
```

2)and in your login activity write this method in on create

```
User user = new User(getApplicationContext());
if (user.getUsername()!=""){
Intent intent = new Intent(this,YourActivity.class);                            
intent.putExtra("username",user.getUsername());
startActivity(intent);}
```

3) Now Extract the username from in YourActivty.class

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
reg_no = intent.getStringExtra("reg_no");
```

and query the database according to it and get the user information

4) So now you gotta add a log out button in your app which will remove the username in the share preference so that a new user can use the app

```
logoutButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()){
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
 AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Home.this);
// Add the buttons
        builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new 
 DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                User user = new User(getApplicationContext());
                user.remove();
                Intent intent ;
          intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),LoginActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);

                // User clicked OK button
            }
        });
        builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                // User cancelled the dialog
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

          // Create the AlertDialog
        builder.setMessage("Do you really want to Log Out ?");

        AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
        dialog.show();

         }}
```

5)In the LoginActivity override the onBackPressed() method and do nothing to make sure that the app doesn't open the previous activity, here I am informing the user that the back button is disabled

```
 @Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    Snackbar.make(binding.main,"That Action is Disabled",Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

//Hope this Helps :)

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at [parse.com](https://parse.com/). They provide all of what you need. Just download their sdk and using their documentation you can start creating all of this.